# ElasticSearch: Aggregations by field of single (filtered) element of nested array

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

There is a list of products.

Each product (document) has such data like id, name, etc.

Also, each document holds specific information per each client (such as **availability**:
given product can be available for one client, and not available for another). This specific information is a nested array.

**'availability'** may hold following values: '**sold_out**', '**available**', '**dead**';

Here is an ES mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "products": {
        "properties": {
            ...
            "clients": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_parent": true,
                "properties": {
                    ...
                    "availability": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed" 
                    }           
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get a count of products which are **sold_out**, **available** and **dead** for given client.
(There is client filter in search params)

```
...
"query": {
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [
        { "term": {"clients.id": 123456789}},        
      ]
    }
  }
...
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, "clients" is a nested array including a non-nested "availability" filter. So, you can have something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path":"clients",
            "filter":{
                "term":{
                    "clients.id": <some_client_id>
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "nestedClient": {
            "nested":{
                "path": "clients",
                "aggs": {
                    "filterClient":{
                        "filter": {
                            "term":{
                                "clients.id":<same_client's_id>
                            }
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "availabilityTerms": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "field": "clients.availability"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query is to narrow down the set of products containing your clients information. Afterwards, you need to filter the nested documents and then run terms aggregation on them. The assumption here is that each product contain only one entry for any particular client. The buckets of the "availabilityTerms" will give you the data you need.